# Angular 1.2 to 1.3 (or newer) form removeControll and addControll issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, migration

I'm migratin app from Angular 1.2 to 1.3. And I'm facing to problem with different behaviour of removeControll and addControll functions.

I have a directive like this, which escaping registered elements in form (don't ask why, We just need it).

```
<div name="es.caped" ng-model="es.caped" esc-dir></div>    

link: function link($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      var nameAttr = $attrs.name.replace(/([ #;?&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@\{\}])/g, '\\$1');
      $ctrl[1].$removeControl($ctrl[0]);
      $ctrl[0].$name = nameAttr;
      $ctrl[1].$addControl($ctrl[0]);
    }
```

And Angular 1.2 will give the wanted result `{"es\\.caped":{}}`.
But 1.3 will give me old value `{"es.caped":{}}`

For more info, how it works see:

1.2 version - [Plunker 1.2 version](https://plnkr.co/edit/LfFKt2rppP3RuGRorweL)

1.3 version - [Plunker 1.3 version](https://plnkr.co/edit/GcU72lmd2RZxsrXNCucD)

Plunker will print result form as a json (1.3 output is more bigger, but you can find the values).

I tried to search in docs and for versions 1.2 and 1.3 there are almost nothing, but for 1.5 I found:

[Note that the current state of the control will not be reflected on the new parent form. This is not an issue with normal use, as freshly compiled and linked controls are in a $pristine state. However, if the method is used programmatically, for example by adding dynamically created controls, or controls that have been previously removed without destroying their corresponding DOM element, it's the developers responsibility to make sure the current state propagates to the parent form](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/docs/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

And I already spent many hours to solve this problem, but with no success. I don't know how to propagate changes. I will be glad for any help.

Note: I tried it also with angular 1.4 and 1.5. And it has same behaviour as 1.3. My final state of migration is 1.5, but I'm following migration guide version by version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem can be solved with this. It will change name of the element and reflect it in the controller.

```
link: function link($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
      var nameAttr = $attrs.name.replace(/([ #;?&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@\{\}])/g, '\\$1');
      $attrs.name = nameAttr ;
}
```